# Angular Material select and Dynamic loading of Items

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a Material Select in Angular and i can load my items fie in select box. But i am trying
to find a way to load the items dynamically. Like user selects in first drop down BMW now on the
next drop down i want to query my db to only show all models of BMW.
The control has 2 @output emitters

```
@Output()
openedChange: EventEmitter<boolean>
@Output()
selectionChange: EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>
```

The first one fires and i can catch it but once there is no data in the list the drop down never drops again and wont emit an event. Is there a way to get an event every time a user clicks on the drop down even before we show the list >

Comment: Hello, we would need more information about the structure of components to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two `select` components, bind to them like:

```html
    <select [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onBrandChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="#b of brands" [value]="b.id">{{b.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCarModel">
        <option *ngFor="#c of carModels" [value]="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Then use that `onBrandChange` method to load the data for the second one:

```js
  onBrandChange(brand: string) {
    // clear options
    this.carModels = [];
    // call your API
    this.apiService.fetchCarModels().subscribe(models => {
      // store car models in the proper property
      this.carModels = models;
    });
  }
```

Comment: yes that's what i was thinking of doing since i could not find a way to load fire an on dropdown or similar event which would do what i was looking for